# SQLite select inside of update

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

So there are 2 tables, `Transactions` with `created_at` column and `Transaction_associations` with `amount` and `remaining_balance` columns, among others. I need to calculate a running sum(total) on the `amount` column, sorted by the `created_at` column, obviously. The only problem is that I need to get the `SUM` of all transactions that are created **before** the current transaction that is being calculated. I would've needed a select inside the update query in order to `SELECT` a `current_transactions` table in order to get hold of the current `created_at` date. However I can't. Am I missing something? Are there alternatives to this method?

```
UPDATE Transaction_associations SET remaining_balance = 
( 
    SELECT SUM (Transaction_associations.amount) 
    FROM Transactions 
    JOIN Transaction_associations ON Transactions.id = transaction_id 
    WHERE created_at <= current_transactions.created_at // here
) 
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM Transaction_associations 
    JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.id = transaction_id 
    WHERE created_at >= '2014-11-24'
)
```

**Edit:** Added example.

```
Transactions     Transaction_associations
created_at       amount     remaining_balance
2014-02-01       100        100
2014-03-01        50        150
2014-04-01       205        355
```

**Later Edit:** Added complete code for use on SQLFiddle. I've replaced Transaction_associations with TA2 on SUM, as it complains of  `misuse of aggregate: SUM()`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Transactions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Transaction_associations;
CREATE TABLE Transactions ( id integer,  created_at text);
CREATE TABLE Transaction_associations ( id integer,  amount integer, remaining_balance integer, transaction_id integer);

  INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES (1,'2015');
  INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES (2,'2014');
  INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES (3,'2013');
  INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES (4,'2012');
  INSERT INTO Transactions VALUES (5,'2010');
  INSERT INTO Transaction_associations VALUES (6, 100, 0, 1);
  INSERT INTO Transaction_associations VALUES (7, 20, 0, 2);
  INSERT INTO Transaction_associations VALUES (8, 3, 0, 3);
  INSERT INTO Transaction_associations VALUES (9, 40, 0, 4);
  INSERT INTO Transaction_associations VALUES (10, 500, 0, 5);



UPDATE Transaction_associations
SET remaining_balance =
(
    SELECT SUM(TA2.amount) 
    FROM Transactions 
    JOIN Transaction_associations AS TA2 ON Transactions.id = TA2.transaction_id
    WHERE created_at <= (SELECT created_at
                         FROM Transactions
                         WHERE id = TA2.transaction_id)
) 
WHERE transaction_id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE created_at >= '2013'
);

SELECT * from Transactions join Transaction_associations on Transactions.id = Transaction_associations.transaction_id;
```

**This results in, which is wrong:**

```
1   2015    6   100 663 1
2   2014    7   20  663 2
3   2013    8   3   663 3
4   2012    9   40  0   4
5   2010    10  500 0   5
```

**Result should be:**

```
1   2015    6   100 663 1
2   2014    7   20  563 2
3   2013    8   3   543 3
4   2012    9   40  0   4
5   2010    10  500 0   5
```

Comment: There is no "current transaction" because you're updating the other table. Add some example data to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, yes. That's the point, what are other alternatives to implement this. I'll update with an example. The point is to calculate the remaining_balance.

Comment: What does this mean? Are these tables in a 1:1 relation?

Comment: No, 1:M, a transaction can have multiple associations. Like I said in the description, those are only a few columns among others.

Comment: How are we supposed to be able to understand your data when you show only a special case?

Comment: It's not a special case. The remaining balance doesn't need to be calculated on multiple transaction associations on the same transaction, but rather by another column, account_id, on the Transaction_associations table. Still, doesn't relate to the current issue.

Comment: So as far as this question is concerned, the relation *is* 1:1?

Comment: Indeed, concerning this issue, you can think of it as a 1:1 relation.

Comment: Why does the last example show updated values for 2010 and 2012?

Comment: My bad, fixed in update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same table name multiple times, rename one of them. This is not possible with UPDATE, so you have to do this in the SELECT.
To look up the corresponding timestamp, use another subquery.
Together with some simplifications, this becomes:

```
UPDATE Transaction_associations
SET remaining_balance =
(
    SELECT SUM(TA2.amount) 
    FROM Transactions 
    JOIN Transaction_associations AS TA2 ON Transactions.id = TA2.transaction_id
    WHERE created_at <= (SELECT created_at
                         FROM Transactions
                         WHERE id = Transaction_associations.transaction_id)
) 
WHERE transaction_id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE created_at >= '2014-11-24'
);
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the entire code, to simplify the process. The problem is that this version doesn't take into consideration the *current* transaction, it just sums them all.

Comment: The innermost query referred to the wrong `Transaction_associations` instance.

Comment: Yep, the right instance gets the job done, thanks. If you have any performance improvement ideas, please let me know.

Comment: That would be a new question.